# Using AutoHotkey to Generate JSON Objects

Tags: json, autohotkey

I have many JSON Messages I must repeatedly push within a cmd console for testing purposes. It'd be convenient to have flexible hotkeys for pushing Test Scenario Message #1, #2, etc, rather than recopy and repaste.

The single-line JSONs I'm pushing take this generic format:

```
//Case1 - message is perfectly formated blah blah
{"field1":"case1Data1","field2":"case1Data2","field3":"case1Data3"..."field12":"case1Data12"}

//Case2 - message has an empty field3 or something blah blah
{"field1":"case2Data1","field2":"case2Data2","field3":""..."field12":"case2Data12"}

//CaseN - message is test scenario N (you get the patterN)
{"field1": "caseNData1",....}
```

Autohotkey has been very helpful in initializing my test environment (opening my shells, starting my various kafka topics, etc). If only it using it for pushing JSONs was as simple as this:

```
;Test Message #1
;Enter a base json here
;Windows+Ctrl+1
#^1::
Send,{"field1":"data1","field2":"data2","field3":"data3"..."field12":"data12"}
Return
```

The problem is with the {} of course. Autokey reserves them for things like the {enter}.

How do I work around this?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/cocobelgica/AutoHotkey-JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use {{} and {}}.

See https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm for this part:

**Key Names**: The following table lists the special keys that can be sent (each key name must be enclosed in braces):

```
Key Name        Resulting Keystroke
{F1} - {F24}    Function keys. For example: {F12} is the F12 key.
{!}             !
{#}             #
{+}             +
{^}             ^
{{}             {
{}}             }
{Enter}         ENTER key on the main keyboard

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SendRaw:

```
;Test Message #1
;Enter a base json here
;Windows+Ctrl+1
#^1::
SendRaw,{"field1":"data1","field2":"data2","field3":"data3"..."field12":"data12"}
Return
```

Also, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33989043/2879085